# Describe the orbitals of transitive $G$ on $\Omega$

Tags: symmetric-groups, group-actions

Suppose $G\lt $ Sym$(\Omega)$ and $G$ acts transitively on $\Omega$ and has rank $3$.

I guess the orbitals may be the diagonal, and two other orbitals with same cardinalities forming from equally splitting the set $\{(x,y)^G|x\ne y, x\in\Omega, y\in\Omega\}$.

But I have no idea how to prove it. Can someone give me a hint or help?

Thanks a lot.

**Update: As @anon pointed out, my guess is wrong. But we deduce that there are only two possible cases for the non-diagonal orbitals. One case is my guess, and the other case corresponds to the example given by @anon.**

Comment: By rank do you mean the minimum number of generators?

Comment: Sorry I forget to give the definition. Rank means the number of orbits of $G$ on $\Omega$ x $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is wrong.

Counterexample: consider the symmetry group $G$ of a tetrahedron (note $G\cong S_4$) acting on the edge set $E$ of size $6$. Then $E^2$ has three orbits: the diagonal pairs (there are $6$ of these), the adjacent pairs (there are $24$ of these) and the disjoint pairs (there are $6$ of these). Note the nondiagonal elements of $E^2$ come in two orbits of different sizes.

Comment: But my guess is on the $\Omega$x$\Omega$, and in your example, $\Omega$x$\Omega$ should be $V$x$V$, where $V$ is the set of vertices of the tetrahedron.

Comment: @SamWong No. I explicitly said $G$ is acting on the set of edges ($\Omega=E$)..

Comment: Sorry I forgot that...

Comment: Emmm, but $G$ seems equal to Sym($E$), right? We need $G\lt $Sym($E$)

Comment: No, $G$ is a proper subgroup of ${\rm Perm}(E)$.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But can we make some classification about possible cases of the non-diagonal orbits of $G$ on $\Omega$x$\Omega$?

Comment: I know primitive group $G$ with rank $3$ has been classified, but the result need a lot of mathematics in algebra. I am just a junior...

Comment: Not that I know off the top of my head.

Comment: I think there are two possible cases. One case is my guess. Another case is that dividing the non-diagonal orbital into two part, and each part is self-paired, i.e. $(x,y)^G=(y,x)^G$, where $(x,y)$ is a element of one of the two parts. The second case corresponds to your example right? Anyway, a lot of thanks to you Anon. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SamWong Yes, that much is true. Either the map $(x,y)\leftrightarrow (y,x)$ is a bijection between the two orbits, or else both orbits are preserved by it.